# How do I enter Game Properties in Steam Library?

Tags: steam

So I'm kinda new to Steam so I'm unsure how to get into Properties in Steam in my Steam Library?

Comment: just right click on the game from the library and click "properties"?

Comment: @Close-Voters - This isn't 'Unclear'. [A Close Vote is not a Super-Downvote. Please don't use it as one](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5498/28182)

Answer (score 2):

When looking at the main Steam interface, click on the 'Library' tab to view your list of games.

From there, you can Right-Click on a Game and Select 'Properties' on the context menu to adjust the settings of that game.

[image: The Steam Interface with the Properties window open]

Click the tabs along the Properties menu to access different options, including DLCs, Game auto-update settings, Verify Local Files and more.